# Building a Docker container using Gitlab CI Docker runner

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am trying to build a docker image using Gitlab Docker runner.

For this I have configured the runner with a shared volume in */etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml* called */builds*:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "My Docker Runner"
  url = "http://host"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache", "/builds"]
  [runners.cache]
```

I created a *.gitlab-ci.yml* in my repo which loosely looks like this:

```
image: alpine:latest

variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: none

test_ci:
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add docker
    - apk add git
    - docker info
    - git clone http://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@host/user/repo.git /builds/user/repo
    - docker build -t database .
    - docker run database
```

I have also created a *Dockerfile* in the repo which looks like this:

```
FROM postgres:9.6

ADD /builds/user/repo/script.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Everything works alright except for the Docker *ADD* instruction which fails because the */builds/user/repo/script.sql* cannot be found:

```
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder886348850/builds/user/repo/script.sql: no such file or directory
```

So I imagine that the */builds* volume I am trying to share between containers is not working as I am expecting it to ... Could someone help me with this? I would like to be able to share the code which is cloned on the runner container to the *docker build* command and then to the newly created container.

Comment: You should add a `ls -alh /builds/user/repo` just before the `docker build` command to ensure the file is there in the container at least, and maybe continue debugging by adding a `sleep 60` to check the content of the directory on the host, as you did mount the docker.sock also.

Comment: The files are there. Actually the `/builds` folder does not exists on the host.

Answer (score 3):

Weird Docker. I changed the *WORKDIR* in the *Dockerfile* and it worked:

```
FROM postgres:9.6

WORKDIR /builds/user/
ADD repo/script.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**EDIT**
The `/builds` folder does not exist on the host system. I thought that adding it to the runner's config would create a volume container that would be shared between containers. But no. So I removed it from the runner config, */etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml*:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "My Docker Runner"
  url = "http://host"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
```